# Regex expression for 8 digits before decimal and 2 after decimal and whole string should not compute to zero

Tags: java, regex, validation, pattern-matching

I need regex expression for the following :

- 8 digits before decimal
- 2 digits after decimal

`\d{0,8}(\.\d{1,2})?$`

this works for the above case , but I don't want the following strings to be accepted. The string should not result to zero.

- 0000.00 -> false
- 00.00 -> false
- 0.0 ->false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is to assert not only dots and zeroes

```
^(?![0.]*$)\d{0,8}(?:\.\d{1,2})?$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SfDrYU/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/kxlxLW)

In Java

```
String regex = "^(?![0.]*$)\\d{0,8}(?:\\.\\d{1,2})?$";
```

If you want a match only, you can omit the capturing group and make it non capturing `(?:`

Comment: This regex doesn't satisfy 1234.45

Comment: It is working , actually when I copied the string it copied two extra slashes

Answer (score 1):

```
"(?=[1-9])(\\d{0,8}(\\.\\d{1,2})?)"
```

A look-ahead with a non-zero digit will do.

Comment: Yes, also look-behind and \R for any newlines: \r, \r\n, NEL

Answer (score 0):

Since this is java and you're using the regex to validate a pattern

`^\d{0,8}(\.\d{1,2})?$`

will get a number with up to two optional decimals.

Once you have this number, you can parse it to a double and check that it isn't equal to 0.

```
String test = "100.00";
if (Pattern.compile("^\\d{0,8}(\\.\\d{1,2})?$").matcher(test).matches()) {
    double val = Double.parseDouble(test);
    if (val > 0) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Anothehr option is to just forget regex, parse it and check if it's within the limits you need

```
final double maxVal = 99999999.99;
String test = "100.00";
try {
    double val = Double.parseDouble(test);
    if (val > 0 && val <= maxVal) {
        int decimalIndex = test.indexOf(".");
        if (decimalIndex >= 0) {
            if (test.length() - decimalIndex - 1 <= 2) {
                // do something, at most two deximals
            }
        } else {
            // do something, no decinals
        }
    }
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    // todo handle exception
}
```

Comment: The parsing to Double method fails to satisfy the 2-decimal-point constraint, e.g. 100.001 has three decimal places but would still pass the test

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I hadn't considered that and have updated the answer accordingly.